# Only the last React component is getting a hover style applied to it

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, hover

I am using next.js and tailwindCSS to style and I made a custom component which has  tags in it. and when you hover over those tags a box is supposed to appear around it. Problem is when i put a couple of these components only the last one gets this effect.

**"index.js"
**

```
import TableRow from "@/components/TableRow";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <TableRow imageurl="https://i.ibb.co/Gp1kWY0/Keeps.png" />
      <TableRow imageurl="https://i.ibb.co/NsK00Vx/Amazon-Pharmacy.png" />
      <TableRow brand="HappyHead" imageurl="https://i.ibb.co/hBffkXR/Happy-Head.png" />
      <TableRow imageurl="https://i.ibb.co/9r9xNZH/hims.png"
          />
        <div className="pb-24"></div>
    </>
  )
}
```

**"_app.js"**

```
import 'tailwindcss/tailwind.css'
import '@/styles/fonts.css'




export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}
```

**"TableRow.js"**

```
import React from 'react';

const TableRow = (props) => {
  
  return (
    <div className="w-[1400px] h-[40px] pt-28 left-56 relative ">
    <div className="w-10/12 pb-4 items-center flex flex-row justify-between">
      <img src={props.imageurl} className="w-[130px] object-contain" alt="keeps" />
      <a className="relative text-center right-16 text-4xl text-blue-500 productpricelink" href={props.foamlink}>${props.foamPrice}</a>
      <a className="relative text-center right-10 text-4xl text-blue-500 productpricelink" href={props.solutionlink}>${props.solutionPrice}</a>
      <a className="relative text-center right-2 text-4xl text-blue-500 productpricelink" href={props.finlink}>${props.finPrice}</a>
    </div>
    <div className="h-[4px] bg-[#D9D9D9]"></div>
  </div>
  
  )
};

export default TableRow;
```

**"fonts.css"**

```
.productpricelink {
    transition: all 0.3s;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  }
    
  .productpricelink:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #2c3e50;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 14px;
}
```

ive tried changing the color of the text inside .productpricelink to see if only some of the components were getting effected by that class, but all of them changed so thats not the problem. Ive tried copy and pasting the last component but still only the last TableRow gets the hover style.

Comment: check the dev tools and see if the .productpricelink:hover role is overridden by other styles.

Comment: @AbouEmran thanks for that suggestion if by devtools you mean like inspect element i checked it out and i can force a state change on an element and when i did the the other componenets were able to get the hover box around them. So i looks like there might be a problem with the other instances of the the TableRow component not detecting the state change?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that my hover state wasn't being detected on my  tags because of overlapping elements. I added a z index attribute to my .productpricelink class and my state change is being detected and working as intended.